# Change selection and status of java installation

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

In Ubuntu I want to change my selection of java to be in auto mode, so I do

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

But it seems that I can only change the `Selection`. How can I also change the `Status` of my selection (jdk8) to be in auto mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives), it says that the priority is set during **- - install** of a symlink to a valid group of jre/jdk. 
The auto mode is used to automatically set the current active (symlink) to the installed group having the highest priority

For instance if you install a new jdk like this :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0.05/bin/java 1
```

The last parameter is the priority. The command creates a link called user/ bin/ java pointing the usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0.05/bin/java binary file and set the priority to one 
You can create all the links this way for all the java binaries...  But inside a package the initscript is executed during installation and creates all the links for you.
Have a look [to this other post](https://askubuntu.com/a/492058/113348)

Comment: I just looked at the man page but I'm too newbie in linux to cook up a solution myself, could you show me how to do it in my case?